# Не получается считать строку в составе которой числа и пробелы

Tags: c

Делаю задачку :3

В задачке надо из ввести число после ввести массив чисел из которого следует найти введенное число (елси оно конечно будет введёном массиве)

Вот мой алгоритм:

```
// 1. подключить библиотеки
// 2. считать строку №1
// 3. проверить строку на правильность ввода число
// 2. считать строку №2
// 3. проверить строку на правильность ввода массив
// 5. проверить нахождение №1 в массиве №2
```

Вот код :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10

int main()
{
    char s[256];    // сюда вводим строку

    int x =0;   // число которое мы ввели
    int texn= 0;  // количество пробелов
    int err =0;
    bool test_fgets=true;


    // 2-3++
    do
    {
        // этот блок для того чтобы отлавливать такие "исключения": вводим 33223йцу, а выводит 33223
        do{
            printf("\nВведите число которое надо найти в массиве:");

            test_fgets=true;
            fgets(s,N,stdin);
            for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++){
                if(test_fgets==true)
                    if(s[i]<'\x30' || s[i]>'\x39'){
                        printf("Ошибка. Повторите ввод!\n"); test_fgets=false;}
            }
        } while(test_fgets!=true);
        // ---

        err=sscanf(s, "%d",&x);
        if (err!=1)
            printf("\n Ошибка ввода. \n ");

    } while (err!=1);

    printf("\n Введено целое число : %d ", x);


    //4-5 --
    // этот блок для того чтобы отлавливать такие "исключения": вводим 33223йцу, а выводит 33223
    do{
        printf("\nВведите массив через пробел:");

        test_fgets=true;
        gets(s);
        for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++){
            if(test_fgets==true){
                if(s[i]<'0' || s[i]>'9'){  // ВОТ тут проблема !!!!
                        test_fgets=false;
                        if(s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\0' || s[i] == '\n'){
                             printf("\n 0!! ");
                            if(s[i] == ' '){printf("\n tecxz! "); texn++;}
                            test_fgets=true;
                        }
                        if(test_fgets == false)
                            printf("Error. Agans vvod!\n");
                 }
            }
        }
    }while(test_fgets!=true);

    printf("\n Vvedena stroka : %s ", s);
    printf("\n texn : %d ", texn);

    return 0;
}
```

в общем в этом блоке не получается считывать строку с числами и пробелами :

```
do{
    //            printf("\nВведите массив через пробел:");
    printf("\n Vvtdite massiw cherez probel:");

    test_fgets=true;
    gets(s);
    for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++){
        if(test_fgets==true){
            if(s[i]<'0' || s[i]>'9'){
                    test_fgets=false;
                    if(s[i] == ' ' ||  s[i] == '\n'){
                         printf("\n 0!! ");
                        if(s[i] == ' '){printf("\n tecxz! "); texn++;}
                        test_fgets=true;
                    }
                    if(test_fgets == false)
                        printf("Error. Agans vvod!\n");
             }
        }
    }
}while(test_fgets!=true);
```

вот вывод чисел:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `char s[256]; if(s[i]<'0' || s[i]>'9')`
И как символ может быть `<0`?

Comment: Легко - это все символы, которые имеют меньшие порядковые номера в ASCII, чем символ '0' (и это совсем не тот ноль, который Вы написали ;-) )

Comment: Это и не должно было сработать. Кто Вам сказал, что после `gets` в Вашей строке будет символ '\n'? Почему Вы не проверяете в условии цикла - не дошли ли до конца строки? Посмотрите, что будет со всеми Вашими условиями, когда станет `s[i] == 0` (а оно рано или поздно станет, т.к. '\n' в Вашей строке нет). PS: и да, лучше `gets` вообще не использовать. `fgets` - безопаснее.

Comment: @Vladimir так что делать то ??? 0_о

Comment: Например, найти длину строки (`strlen`) и делать цикл не до '\n', а по количеству реальных символов. Ну или в условие выхода из `for` добавить символ '\0'. И тогда, вроде бы, до `printf("Error. Agans vvod!\n");` уже не должно доходить при правильном вводе.

Comment: Попробуйте для чтения чисел из строки использовать [strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll), она как раз сконструирована для упрощения ввода списка чисел из строки.

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов В коде написано `< '0'`, а не `< 0`. Вы не замечаете разницы?

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке языка С уже давно нет функции `gets`. Поэтому не ясно, что `gets` делает в вашем коде и зачем вообще сделана эта мешанина из `fgets` и `gets`. Почему вы просто не пользуетесь `fgets` везде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы удалось только, по "символьному" через `getchar` :

```
do{
        printf("Введите строку положительных чисел:\n");
        test_fgets=true;

        int i_t=0;

        while((c= getchar()) != EOF){
            if (c >='0' && c <= '9'){
                wwod[t_G_p][i_t] = c; wwod_t[t_G_p] = i_t ;  i_t++;
            }
            else if (c == ' ' || c == '\t'){
                t_G_p++; i_t=0;
            }
            else if (c == '\n'){
                  break;
            }
            else{
                test_fgets=false; t_G_p =0;  printf("Введите строку без символов письма !\n");
            }
        }
    }while(test_fgets!=true);
```

Вот вся программа :

```
// 1. подключить библиотеки
// 2. считать строку №1
// 3. проверить строку на правильность ввода число
// 2. считать строку №2
// 3. проверить строку на правильность ввода массив
// 5. проверить нахождение №1 в массиве №2

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main()
{
    char s[256];    // сюда вводим строку
    int c;  // для гетчар
    int t_G_p  = 0;  // датчик отлав колич чисел в строке
    char wwod[256][256]; // двух-слойный массив
    int wwod_t[256]; // массив в котором лежат размерности переменных массива

    int x =0;   // число которое мы ввели
    int chisla_mass[256]; //числа которые будем считать

    int err =0;    // ошибка
    bool test_fgets=true; // датчик

    // 2-3++
    do
    {
        // этот блок для того чтобы отлавливать такие "исключения": вводим 33223йцу, а выводит 33223
        do{
            printf("\nВведите число которое надо найти в массиве:");

            test_fgets=true;
            fgets(s,N,stdin);
            for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++){
                if(test_fgets==true)
                    if(s[i]<'\x30' || s[i]>'\x39'){
                        printf("Ошибка. Повторите ввод!\n"); test_fgets=false;}
            }
        } while(test_fgets!=true);
        // ---

        err=sscanf(s, "%d",&x);
        if (err!=1)
            printf("\n Ошибка ввода. \n ");

    } while (err!=1);

    printf("\n Введено целое число : %d \n", x);


    //4-5 --
    do{
        printf("Введите строку положительных чисел:\n");
        test_fgets=true;

        int i_t=0;

        while((c= getchar()) != EOF){
            if (c >='0' && c <= '9'){
                wwod[t_G_p][i_t] = c; wwod_t[t_G_p] = i_t ;  i_t++;
            }
            else if (c == ' ' || c == '\t'){
                t_G_p++; i_t=0;
            }
            else if (c == '\n'){
                  break;
            }
            else{
                test_fgets=false; t_G_p =0;  printf("Введите строку без символов письма !\n");
            }
        }
    }while(test_fgets!=true);


    int i =0;
    for ( i =0; i <= t_G_p; i++){
        err=sscanf(wwod[i], "%d",&chisla_mass[i]);
        printf("число : %d \n",chisla_mass[i]);
    }

    //-----
    int q_q_t = 0;
    for ( i =0; i <= t_G_p; i++){
         if(chisla_mass[i] == x){
             printf("Есть похожее(идентично-натуральному) число !!!!! \n");
             q_q_t = 1;}
    }

    if(q_q_t == 0)
        printf("Числа увы нету ;_; \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот "снимок" экрана :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Конкретная ошибка (видимо о ней и спрашивает автор) во втором фрагменте кода в том, что [gets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) удаляет символ '\n' из считанной строки

> gets() reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to by s until
>   either a terminating newline or EOF, which it replaces with a null
>   byte.

Поэтому цикл

```
for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++) { 
  ... 
}
```

"проскакивает" **за конец введенных данных** и анализ уже "мусора в памяти" (а не введенных символов) вызывает выполнение

```
         test_fgets=false;
```

не заходит внутрь

```
         if(s[i] == ' ' ||  s[i] == '\n'){
           .....
           test_fgets=true;
         }
```

а затем выполняется

```
         if(test_fgets == false)
            printf("Error. Agans vvod!\n");
```

Что мы и наблюдаем (но не ожидаем, поскольку вводили только цифры и пробелы).

---

Резюме -- внимательно читайте *man pages* (и используйте `fgets()` (возможно лучше даже [getline()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) для чтения строк).

Comment: А можно ли решить эту задачу без создания файла (а то fgets() и getline() что бы с ними работать надо файл создавать) ???

Comment: я просто не могу понять зачем в считывающей строке fgets() и getline() нужно создавать файл, с чём связана такая политика?  Просто в книге _язык СИ справочник принца Питера_ (ака **коровка :3** ) . Там работа с "считыванием строки" (ввод-вывод) , почему-то вся через файл.

Comment: @timob256, вам не нужно создавать файл, чтобы использовать `fgets`. `fgets` последним параметром принимает `FILE *`. Этим последним параметром вы можете передать `stdin` и тогда строка будет считываться со стандартного потока ввода (в вашем случае - через терминал).